# How to get access denied for files logged in WIndows event log

Tags: windows, security, logging

I need to log access denied events for files and directories on a Windows Server 2008 R2. How do I go about getting them into the Windows Event Log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn auditing on, on the directories.  See [What is Windows Auditing?](http://www.petri.co.il/windows_auditing.htm) and  [Audit File System](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772661(WS.10).aspx) Depending on your need, you should also consider enabling global object access auditing See [Global Object Access Auditing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772630(WS.10).aspx)